# Minimizing distance to a point with very complicated constraint

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, numerical-methods

For any point `x`, I am trying to use `sciPy` to get the closest point in `x_W` of a quite complicated region, but I am unable to make it work.

The region is defined by a very nasty function `f` defined as in the image:

[image]

I used the following code

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np

def Dist(v1, v2):
    if type(v1) is not np.ndarray:
        v1 = np.array(v1)
    if type(v2) is not np.ndarray:
        v2 = np.array(v2)

    return np.abs(np.sum((v1-v2)**2))


cons = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda V: V[18] * ( (((V[0]*V[3] - V[1]*V[2])/np.sqrt((V[0]+V[1])*(V[2]+V[3]))) * 1/np.sqrt((1-V[16]-V[18]*(V[0]+V[2]))*(V[16]+V[18]*(V[0]+V[2])))) + (((V[4]*V[7] - V[5]*V[6])/np.sqrt((V[4]+V[5])*(V[6]+V[7]))) * 1/np.sqrt((1-V[17]-V[18]*(V[4]+V[6]))*(V[17]+V[18]*(V[4]+V[6])))) + (((V[8]*V[11] - V[9]*V[10])/np.sqrt((V[8]+V[9])*(V[10]+V[11]))) * 1/np.sqrt((1-V[16]-V[18]*(V[8]+V[10]))*(V[16]+V[18]*(V[8]+V[10])))) - (((V[12]*V[15] - V[13]*V[14])/np.sqrt((V[12]+V[13])*(V[14]+V[15]))) * 1/np.sqrt((1-V[17]-V[18]*(V[12]+V[14]))*(V[17]+V[18]*(V[12]+V[14])))) ) - 2})

bnds = ((0,1),)*19

pnt = (.5, .5, .5, .5, .5, .5,0, .5, .5, 0, 0, .5, 0, .5, .5, 0, .5, .45, .45)
PRstart = ((.5, 0, 0, .5, .5, 0, 0, .5, .5, 0, 0, .5, 0, .5, .5, 0, .5, .5, .5))
out = opt.minimize(Dist, PRstart, args=(np.array(pnt)), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

I used that starting point since I know it is a valid starting point that gives $f = 2$.

My problem is that I keep getting the `invalid value encountered in sqrt` error, which tells me that at some points it evaluates a complex number from the square roots, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mind to share the reference for the formula?

Comment: I came up with it. It is actually a CHSH inequality. The reason I have them in groups of a, b, c ,d is because they add up to 1 for each subindex. I am not interested in using the constraint.

Comment: is it the  capital `P` on RHS of `g` a typos?

Comment: Should your solution be real or complex? If you work only with real numbers, you can add to `cons` constraints of positivity to the expressions under the square roots. And make sure to use strictly positive constraints to avoid a zero division error

Comment: I can't see `x` nor `x_W` in the equations !?

Comment: Yes, it should be a lower case p @rpanai

Comment: For starts, you should definitely define `g` as its own function and then use `g` in your definition of `f`. It'll be easier to see what's going on.